# Magento 2 - Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded

Tags: database, magento2.2.2, server-setup, setup-upgrade

I am upgrading a website from Magento 2.2 to 2.5 and running into an error. I read through a lot of threads and forums but nothing is working. This includes adding

max_execution_time 60000, set_time_limit(0) in my php.ini

I am using Cloudways and they said any PHP directives defined in a .htaccess will not be used. To use PHP-FPM Settings.

I added the following values:
[image]

I restarted my server and looked into my phpinfo() and saw the changes I made were the same values in the image attached.

---

**Preconditions**

1. Running Magento 2.2.2, upgrading to 2.2.5
2. I have 1 website 1 store 4 store views. Over 250k orders and about 400 products.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.5 --no-update
2. composer update
3. rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
4. php bin/magento setup:upgrade

**Expected result**

1. The Magento 2.2.2 upgrades to 2.2.5.

**Actual result**

1. Time to upgrade takes longer than 300 seconds.
2. The maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in /home/150747.cloudwaysapps.com/qqemzvkvdx/public_html/vendor/magento/frame
   work/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111

Thanks for reading. Anything helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seemed to be fixed in M2.2.6

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run this

```
php -d max_execution_time=252900 memory_limit=10G  bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

**instead of**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

It will override your PHP env value during upgrade command.

Also, Stop all Cronjob during the upgrade process.
And Before start upgrade process delete this two files `.setup_cronjob_status,var/.update_cronjob_status` from `var/`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

I tried running the command and I get the error

**Could not open input file: memory_limit=10G**

I ran the command without memory_limit, deleted and stopped Cronjob you recommended but still get the same **Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded**